# Writing an SQL query to return all fields from 2 sqlite tables (Android app)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I'm creating a fitness app where workout info can be saved to 2 tables (TABLE_CARDIO for cardio activity and TABLE_WEIGHTS for weight training activity). Below is the structure of the 2 tables:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FitnessTracker.db";
public static final String TABLE_WEIGHTS = "saved_workout_weights";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "DATE";
public static final String COL_3 = "EXERCISE";
public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
public static final String COL_5 = "REPS";
public static final String COL_6 = "SETS";

public static final String TABLE_CARDIO = "saved_workout_cardio";
public static final String COL_1a = "ID";
public static final String COL_2a = "DATE";
public static final String COL_3a = "TIME";
```

I then have the following method with a query for selecting all data from both tables (which is what I need):

```
public Cursor getWorkoutData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + "FULL OUTER JOIN " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + "ON" + TABLE_CARDIO.DATE = TABLE_WEIGHTS.DATE; ;
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, within the query, I'm trying to join the 2 tables using the 'DATE' field as a foreign key. However, android studio is highlighting 'DATE' in red and throwing the error 'Cannot resolve symbol'.

I know there are some similar questions to this up here but I've been unable to implement any of the solutions in to my scenario. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot to place `"="`. Your query should be like following

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " FULL OUTER JOIN " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + " ON " + TABLE_CARDIO.DATE + " = " + TABLE_WEIGHTS.DATE;
```

Dont forget to place whitespaces around of sql keywords.

**Added**

Another thing is ambigous field names. So you need to place table names before fields.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " FULL OUTER JOIN " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + " ON " + TABLE_CARDIO + ".DATE = " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + ".DATE";
```

And please don't use `select * from ...` queries. :-)

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you!